# In a group, if $g^{-1}h\in S(x)$ (stabilizer), then $gS(x)=hS(x)$ (as left cosets).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, orbit-stabilizer

I'll write down the definitons I'm using.

Let $G$ be a group and $X$ a set. We say $\bullet$ is a left group action of $G$ on $X$ if the function $$G\times X\to X$$
$$(g,x)\mapsto g \bullet x$$
satisfies

1. $e\bullet x=x~\forall x\in X$,
2. $g\bullet (h\bullet x)=(gh)\bullet x~\forall x \in X~\forall g,h\in G.$

The **orbit** of $x\in X$ is the set $G\bullet x=\mathcal O_x=\{g\bullet x:g \in G\}$ (if $\bullet$ is a left group action of $G$ on $X$).

The **stabilizer** (under the same hypothesis as orbit) of $x$, is the set $$S(x)=\{g\in G: g\bullet x=x\}.$$

The **index** of a subgroup $H<G$ is the number of left (or right, they have the same cardinality) cosets of $H$. The **left cosets** of $H$ in $G$ are the sets $gH=\{gh:h\in H\}$ for each $g\in G$.

If $H<G$, then $G/H=\{gH:g\in G\}$ is the quotient of $G$ by $H$, which is a subgroup if $H$ is a **normal** subgroup of $G$ ($Nx=xN~\forall x\in G$), otherwise it is just a set.

I've alredy proved that the stabilizer is a subgroup of $G$, i.e. $S(x)<G$.

I'm trying to understand the proof for the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem:

> If $G$ is a group and $X$ a set such that $\bullet$ is a left group action of $G$ on $X$, then $$|\mathcal{O}_x|=[G:S(x)]~\forall x \in X.$$

The proof is:

> Let $x\in X$. We can define the function $$F:\mathcal{O}_x\to G/S(x)$$
> $$g\bullet x\mapsto F(g\bullet x)=gS(x).$$
> We need to prove it is well-defined. Let's pick $g,h\in G$ such that $g\bullet x=h\bullet x$, then:
> $$g\bullet x=h\bullet x\iff (g^{-1}h)\bullet x=x\iff g^{-1}h\in S(x)\color{red}{\iff}gS(x)=hS(x).$$

The red $\color{red}{\iff}$ is what I don't understand. I can see it is true if the subgroup if normal, but why in the case we are just doing the quotient of groups which is a set, that is true?
I could think of $g^{-1}h\in S(x)\iff h\in g S(x)$ but not the other way round.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Trivial by left congruence $\mod S(x)$.

Comment: For any subgroup $H$ of $G$, $a^{-1}b \in H \!\iff\! aH=bH$. Indeed, if $a^{-1}b \in H$, then $ah = b(a^{-1}b)^{-1}h \in bH$ for every $h \in H$ and $bh=a(a^{-1}b)h \in aH$ for every $h \in H$; so $aH=bH$. Conversely, if $aH=bH$, then $a \in bH$ and so there exists $h \in H$ such that $a=bh$; hence , $a^{-1}b=h^{-1} \in H$.

Comment: Your subject line is wrong. $gh^{-1}\in S(x)\iff S(x)g=S(x)h$ (right cosets). It's different from what you have in the post.

Comment: -1 until you fix the subject line

Comment: I don't know what are you saying...

Comment: The subject line to your post contains makes an incorrect statement. And I have downvoted your post until you fix it. You have the cosets on the wrong side in the subject line.

Comment: What you mean by subject line, the title of the post? I just wrote cosets there.

Comment: I mean the line that appears above your post, that says **"In a group, if $gh^{-1}\in S(x)$ (stabilizer), then $gS(x) =hS(x)$ (as cosets)."** You know, the line that when you edit says "Title". For the third time, that statement is **incorrect**. You only wrote cosets, but you used **left** cosets: $gS(x)$ and $hS(x)$.

Comment: Sigh. You don't get it. The claim that if $gh^{-1}\in K$ then $gK=hK$ is **wrong**. The condition $gh^{-1}\in K$ is the condition for equality of **right** cosets. $gK=hK\iff g^{-1}h\in K$, and $Kg=Kh \iff gh^{-1}\in K$. So now you've edited your title so that it is **clear** that you don't know what you are saying.

Comment: Note that in the post itself you **correctly** write "$g^{-1}h\in S(x)\iff gS(x)=hS(x)$". But in the title you write $gh^{-1}$ instead. **Not the same thing.** And not equivalent, either.

Comment: Finally..........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true for any coset. Namely, let $H\leq G$. Then $gH=H\Leftrightarrow g\in H$. So, $gkH = H\Leftrightarrow gk\in H$. Furthermore, $g^{-1}kH=H \Leftrightarrow g^{-1}k\in H$. But we clearly see that $g^{-1}kH=H\Leftrightarrow kH=gH$ (multiply on the left by $g$).